# How to turn a simple class into a KVC for binding to a CollectionViewItem

Tags: mvvmcross, monomac

I have a simple class

```
public class Colora
{
    public Colora()
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

that needs to stay simple (it is in a PCL). How do I turn this into a KVC compliant NSObject so that it can be displayed in a CollectionView?

I was thinking something like

```
        List<Colora> coloras = new List<Colora> () {
            new Colora() { Name = "Red" },
            new Colora() { Name = "Blue" }
        };
        var objs = new NSObject[coloras.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < coloras.Count; i++) {
            objs [i] = NSObject.FromObject (coloras [i]);
        }       
        devCollectionView.Content = objs;
```

but FromObject does not work with my class. In this case the array does not have to be mutable.

**Update.** Remarkably, this works

```
public class ColoraViewModel : NSObject
{
    private readonly Colora _colora;
    public ColoraViewModel (Colora colora)
    {
        _colora = colora;
    }

    [Export("name")]
    public string Name {
        get { return _colora.Name; }
        set {
            if (_colora.Name != value) {
                _colora.Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
        List<Colora> coloras = new List<Colora> () {
            new Colora() { Name = "Red" },
            new Colora() { Name = "Blue" }
        };
        var objs = new NSObject[coloras.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < coloras.Count; i++) {
            objs [i] = new ColoraViewModel (coloras [i]);
        }       
        devCollectionView.Content = objs;
```

though I'm still looking for a general way to create the KVC without having to make a new ViewModel.

This doesn't work, but I dream of something like this:

```
public class KVCObject : NSObject
{
    private readonly object _t;
    private readonly Type _type;


    public KVCObject (object t)
    {
        _t = t;
        _type = t.GetType();
    }

    public override void SetValueForKey (NSObject value, NSString key)
    {
        var info = _type.GetProperty (key.ToString ());
        info.SetValue (_t, value);
    }

    public override NSObject ValueForKey (NSString key)
    {
        var info = _type.GetProperty (key.ToString ());
        return NSObject.FromObject(info.GetValue (_t));
    }
}
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" sounds like it's starting in the right direction - but you may need to support more methods than that. Some of the code in https://github.com/iKenndac/KNFoundation may be helpful

Comment: I got KVCObject to "work" one way.

Comment: I haven't found a way to make a generic 'KVCObject'. I use ViewModels as per your working sample, only I generate them using a T4 template. Creating the template was a fairly significant chunk of work, but it's automated all of this repetitive work

Comment: @TheNextman a T4 template seems reasonable. The KVCObject is close - but I'm not sure about performance.

Comment: KNFoundation looks promising